# ExcelJs - SaxesParser error: duplicate attribute

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I'm trying to open a workbook with exceljs and get the following error:

```
Error: 162:67: duplicate attribute: o:relid.
    at SaxesParser.makeError (C:\Users\tiedemann\Development\mbes32-events\node_modules\saxes\saxes.js:410:16)
    at SaxesParser.fail (C:\Users\tiedemann\Development\mbes32-events\node_modules\saxes\saxes.js:422:26)
    at SaxesParser.processAttribsPlain (C:\Users\tiedemann\Development\mbes32-events\node_modules\saxes\saxes.js:1944:22)
    at SaxesParser.openSelfClosingTag (C:\Users\tiedemann\Development\mbes32-events\node_modules\saxes\saxes.js:1976:14)
    at SaxesParser.sOpenTagSlash (C:\Users\tiedemann\Development\mbes32-events\node_modules\saxes\saxes.js:1432:18)
    at SaxesParser.write (C:\Users\tiedemann\Development\mbes32-events\node_modules\saxes\saxes.js:481:36)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\tiedemann\Development\mbes32-events\node_modules\exceljs\lib\utils\parse-sax.js:21:17)
    at async VmlNotesXform.parse (C:\Users\tiedemann\Development\mbes32-events\node_modules\exceljs\lib\xlsx\xform\base-xform.js:60:22)
```

I really tried hard to find any informations on that error. But can't make sense out of the informations google give me. Could anyone of you give me a hint what is wrong here?

I guess it has something todo with the xml. But I can't figure out what exactly todo or change in my file.

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. In the file was a circular reference in one of the cells. After removing the formular from that cell and saving the workbbok again. The error disappered. Wished the error message were more helpful in advance.